# Why are split bobbin cores not used for distribution transformers (10kVA and up)?

Tags: power, transformer

Why are split bobbin cores not used for distribution transformers (10kVA and up)?

They are available for low voltage but are not so popular for high voltage. Why?

Comment: At a rough guess, in those sizes you're counting every last tenth of a percent inefficiency, and the increased leakage inductance just doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 1):

The leakage inductance is higher with split bobbin transformers, so they have worse regulation, all other things being equal.

Split bobbin transformers are good for relatively high breakdown voltage between primary and secondary.